# Sorted moves implementation for minimax results in an infinite loop

Tags: python, chess

I am writing a simple chess ai. My minimax algorithm seems to work well with a list of legal moves. I tried adding a function to sort the moves based on capture value. Whenever I try to get minimax to work with a list that is returned from that function, it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

```
#move ordering algorithm
def order_moves(BOARD, moves):
  
  ordered_moves = []

  for move in moves:
    #go through the legal moves and check if there is a piece captured
    if BOARD.is_capture(move):
      moving_piece = BOARD.piece_at(move.from_square)
      captured_piece = BOARD.piece_at(move.to_square)
      
      #get capture value by subtracting moving from captured piece
      #it is important to get absolute values for both since black pawn =-100, while white =100
      #and append the move and value to a list
      if captured_piece is not None:
        capture_value = (abs(PIECE_VALUE[captured_piece.symbol()])-abs(PIECE_VALUE[moving_piece.symbol()]))
        ordered_moves.append((move, capture_value))
        
  #sort through the list for moves with best capture value
  ordered_moves.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
  sorted_moves = [move[0] for move in ordered_moves]
  
  return sorted_moves
```

I have tried debugging the move ordering with print statements and it is unclear what is exactly the issue here. Below is the minimax function. I have made sure it checks for empty arrays, in case that was the issue, but it did not fix anything.

```
# minimax algorithm
def minimax(BOARD, DEPTH, MAXIMIZE, counter, alpha=-math.inf, beta=math.inf):
  
    # create a list of legal moves and counter
    moves = list(BOARD.legal_moves)
    counter = counter + len(moves)
    opening_move = reader.get(BOARD)
  
    # initialize best move and scores
    max_score = -math.inf
    min_score = math.inf
    best_move = None
  
    # make sure depth is >1 and there are legal moves
    if DEPTH == 0 or not moves:
        return None, counter

    # prioritize playing book moves
    opening_move = reader.get(BOARD)
    if opening_move is not None:
        best_move = opening_move.move
        return best_move, counter

    # check for checkmate before proceeding with moves
    outcome = BOARD.outcome()
    if outcome is not None and outcome.result() in ["1-0", "0-1"]:
        return None, counter + 1

    #order the moves
    ordered_moves = order_moves(BOARD, moves)
    
    # if maximizing player, select the best move
    #go through all moves
    if ordered_moves is None:
      return None, counter
    else:
      for i in ordered_moves:
        b = deepcopy(BOARD)
        b.push(i)
        # recursively call minimax with the new board
        temp_move, temp_counter = minimax(b, DEPTH - 1, not MAXIMIZE, counter, alpha, beta)

        # push temp move and get the counter
        if temp_move is not None:
            b.push(temp_move)
            counter = temp_counter
        # evaluate the board and get node score
        score = evals(b, PIECE_VALUE, MAXIMIZE)
        # if maximizer, set the best move to the best score
        if MAXIMIZE:
            alpha = max(alpha, score)
            if score > alpha:
                alpha = score
            # if new score is better than stored max score, assign i as the best move
            if score > max_score:
                max_score = score
                best_move = i
        # if minimizer, set the best move to the worst score
        else:
            beta = min(beta, score)
            if score < beta:
                beta = score
            # if new score is worse than stored min score, assign i as the best move
            if score < min_score:
                min_score = score
                best_move = i
        if beta <= alpha:
            break
    return best_move, counter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in ordered_moves function. If there were no captures (e.i a check) the function returned an empty list, so there were no moves to choose from. By adding this:

```
else:
  #if there is no piece captured, add the move and -1 value to a list
  move_value = -1
ordered_moves.append((move, move_value))
```

the function appended all moves, including non-captures, to the list before returning it to the minimax.